# Wrong multiplication in PHP

Tags: php, multiplication, operation

I'm trying to do a simple operation of two numbers but the operation returns a wrong result.

The number are for example `46.29` and `10`. The first one in the `$a` variable and the second one in the `$b` variable.

**Process**

```
echo $a * $b
```

> returns 460

```
echo 10 * 46.29
```

> print the right number (462.90)

```
$a * 10
```

and

```
46.29 * $b
```

> result is always the same: 460!

```
echo $a
```

> print 46,29

```
echo $b
```

> print 10

```
echo floatval($a) * floatval($b)
```

> print 460

```
echo intval($a)
```

> print 46

I tried also to use `bcmul`, and in this case it will print 0.

Here you can find my code:

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

     $anno = $_POST['Anno'];
     $punti = $_POST['Punti'];
     $eta = $_POST['Eta'];
     $ggAss = $_POST['GgAss'];
     $ggParz1 = $_POST['GgParz1'];
     $ggParz2 = $_POST['GgParz2'];
     $ggParz3 = $_POST['GgParz3'];
     $pctDM = $_POST['PctDM'];
     $calcoloDM = $_POST['CalcoloDannoMorale'];
     $speseMediche = $_POST['SpeseMediche'];
     $spese = $_POST['Spese'];

    $html = file_get_html('..\tabella'.$anno.'.php');

    $rows = $html->find('tr');

    // This variable is use to make sure that the correct number will be display. (there is a kind of offset in the output table).
    $const = 2;


    $i = 0;
    $cond = false;
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $j = 0;
        foreach ($row->children() as $cell) {
            if($cond)
                break;
            //This condition is used to get punto base e indennità giornaliera
            if($i == 1) {
                $var1 = explode(" ", $cell->plaintext);
                $indennitaGG = $var1[10]; // here we can get indennità giornaliera
            }
            if($i == ($eta + $const) && $j == $punti) {
                $dannoBP = $cell->plaintext;
                $cond = true;
                break;
            }
            $j++;
        }
        $i++;
    }

    $calcIndGG = $indennitaGG * $ggAss;
    $newVar = $indennittaGG;
    echo 46.29 * 10;
    $calcIndParz1 = ($indennitaGG * 75 / 100) * $ggParz1;
    $calcIndParz2 = ($indennitaGG * 50 / 100) * $ggParz2;
    $calcIndParz3 = ($indennitaGG * 25 / 100) * $ggParz3;
    $dm = ($calcIndGG + $calcIndParz1 + $calcIndParz2 + $calcIndParz3) * $pctDM / 100;

    $totale = $dannoBP + $calcIndGG + $calcIndParz1 + $calcIndParz2 + $calcIndParz3 + $dm + $speseMediche + $spese;
```

What's the problem with this?

EDIT:
PROBLEM SOLVED with this code:

```
//This change is used to transform the variable $indennitaGG in the right form. (with the . and not with the ,). Then we can make the cast to float.


    $temp = str_replace(",",".", $indennitaGG);
        $indennitaGG = (float)$temp;
```

Comment: echo the values of `$a` and `$b` before you do the multiplication.

Comment: when your values are in the variables are they the correct type? i.e. an int or float and not a string

Comment: yes, sure. I tried to print both numbers and both are the correct numbers.

Comment: Try to use `floatval($a) * floatval($b)` they are probably not the same type and PHP misinterprets them.

Comment: If i try to do:
echo $a // print 46,29
echo $b // print 10
echo $a * $b // print 460
echo floatval($a) * floatval($b) // print 460
echo 46.29 * 10 // print 462.90

Comment: What is the output of `echo intval($a)`?

Comment: 46. The right expected number :\

Comment: Give us code so we can recreate it on our computers.

Comment: So that's the problem! Try `str_replace(",",".",$a); echo floatval($a) * floatval($b);`

Comment: Please extract the required minimal example before posting here. It makes sure that the problem really is where you guess it is and removes external influences that others can't reproduce.

Answer (score 4):

The `,` character is not valid for a floating point number.
Try to replace it with `str_replace(",",".",$a);`. Even try to do it with both numbers if you wish.

The "official" decimal separator (for PHP) is a point (`.`), that's why it fails doing the multiplication. In your language it might be the comma, but PHP uses a dot.

**This is what PHP would say (to `floatval($a)`):**

> Ok, I got two characters, which is a valid number (`46`),
>   but after that there's a weird symbol, I'll just throw a warning, add a decimal point and a zero (cause I found no other decimal points), and
>   end the conversion here.

**If you use this code, it should work:**

```
str_replace(",",".",$a);
str_replace(",",".",$b);
echo floatval($a) * floatval($b);
```

**Explanation:**

As I said, you're using a *decimal comma*, which is invalid. What `str_replace(original, replacement, subject)` does is that it finds all occurrences of *original* in a string (here: *subject*) and replaces it with the *replacement* value. This results in replacing that *decimal comma* with a *decimal point*.

Example: `40,3` becomes `40.3`

This still results in a *String* data type, which is obviously not a number. To convert it, we use the method `floatval(string)`, which results in a *Float* data type, which is short for Floating-point number and after that, we can perform arithmetical operations.

Answer (score 3):

Your `locale` is using a different sign for the decimal point. I suspect when you read the numbers from a file they are in the "wrong" format - e.q. `46,29` and not `46.29` as I can see from the `echo`.

Replace the `,` to `.` and then the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you run this code, you'll get the correct result.

```
$a = 10;
$b = 46.29;
echo $a * $b;
```

echo $a and $b before you get to the math. If the numbers are correct, cast them like this.

echo floatval($a) * floatval($b);

If these aren't working, you'll need to give us the right code to recreate the issue. Your full code depends on post variables and an include. Give us just the code to recreate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try to cast themas a float before using them. this should probably work. If its not, what types do you get when you use *`var_dump()`*?

Comment: I see that the type is string ... *_*

Comment: so that is your problem.

Comment: try `echo (float)$a * (float)$b;`.

Comment: I found the problem as you suggest, but now i can't do the cast to float *_* if i try to print (float)$a * (float)$b it will print 460 :\